# Why isn't this code binding a click event to the A tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="osoba listItem podrucjaDjelovanja" id="listItem1"  style='display:block'>
  <h3>..</h3>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>Areas of practice:  
    <a href="/en/aktivnosti/#listItem1A">general legal support</a>, 
    <a href="/en/aktivnosti/#listItem2A">conciliation</a>, 
    <a href="/en/aktivnosti/#listItem4A">civil and commercial contracts </a>, 
    <a href="/en/aktivnosti/#listItem8A">property management</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to bind the onClick event to the a tag. I'm using this call:

```
$('.navLeft .menu-item a, #upper-header a, #logo, .podrucjaDjelovanja p a').on('click', function(event) {
```

which works great for all cases except this one (the last one). When I click the link, this binding is ignored. I'm unsure what I could be doing wrong.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, I think it will be easier if I point you to the page then copy paste a lot of code. Basically, the page is http://skrobotwp.gandzo.com/en/zaposlenici/ and the listener is defined in ajax.js line 36.

Comment: Have you debugged the selector? Does it select the <a> elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "binding is ignored"? What are you doing in the handler?

Comment: We will need a little more code.

Comment: are the links in `.podrucjaDjelovanja` generated dynamically using ajax?

Comment: Binding is ignored means when I click on the link and try to debug the first line (event.preventDeafult()) the first line isn't called, and when I inspect the code with Chrome inspector, there aren't any bindings on them.

Comment: The code is generated dynamically, but if you use the direct link then the code is already in the page, ajax calls are made from other pages.

Comment: You have: `if (event.target.href !== APP)` - where is `APP` being defined?

Comment: In the header, along with HOME

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is not the first line of the handler.  Are you *sure* the handler isn't getting called?  Put a `console.log()` statement or an `alert()` as the **first** line of the event handler.

Comment: I'm sure because it's called when I click on the menu link (the '.navLeft .menu-item a' part of the call)

Comment: @Andrija Check the answer I posted. I think that should solve your issue.

Comment: Your event handler has different logic depending on which element it runs on.  You *can't* say that because it works for a different element it should work for these elements.  It would take seconds to put a logging statement in there to check.  Stop guessing and make sure.

Comment: @Jim I have mentioned that I tried with debugging and inspecting the binding on the element itself. I don't know why you think I'm guessing, I'm wrote I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned debugging "the first line", which, by inspecting your actual code, *is not the first line*.  If there is an error in the code preceding whichever line you are attaching the debugger to, it can raise an exception, quitting the event handler before your debugger sees that it has been called, thus misleading you into thinking that the event handler has not been called at all, leading you to look in an entirely incorrect place for the mistake.

Comment: All I am saying is verify that the situation is how you think it is by taking the *few seconds* to debug correctly instead of skipping ahead to where you guess the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think the problem is how you call the `.on` function. Before jQuery 1.7 they had separate methods for `.bind`, `.delegate` and `.live`. But with arrival of jQuery 1.7 these methods were deprecated to simplify things by including them all under 1 method `.on`. But due to not so clear documentation people don't understand the `.on` method. `.on` does provide the function of 3 above mentioned deprecated methods, but it depends how you use `.on` method. Here is an example:

```
// Bind
$( ".podrucjaDjelovanja p a" ).on( "click", function( e ) {} ); 

// Live
$( document ).on( "click", ".podrucjaDjelovanja p a", function( e ) {} );

// Delegate
$( ".podrucjaDjelovanja" ).on( "click", "p a", function( e ) {} );
```

My guess is that markup for the anchor tags that are not working are being declared after your `.on` call. In that case you will have to implement the `.on` as done for live events. So all you would need to change is the way you call `.on`.

```
$(document).on( "click", ".navLeft .menu-item a, #upper-header a, #logo, .podrucjaDjelovanja p a", function( event ) {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is somewhere outside the code that you have shown.

It works just fine with the code from your question: http://jsfiddle.net/p4DRg/

```
$('.navLeft .menu-item a, #upper-header a, #logo, .podrucjaDjelovanja p a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(1);
});
```

Perhaps there is some invalid tag somehere that makes the elements end up different from what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code in the `JQuery ready`?

This works fine for me:

```
$(function(){
 $('.navLeft .menu-item a, #upper-header a, #logo, .podrucjaDjelovanja p a')
    .on('click',   function(event) {
      console.log($(this));
      return false;
 });
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvDX8/

Answer (score 0):

Run `console.log($('.navLeft .menu-item a, #upper-header a, #logo, .podrucjaDjelovanja p a'));` to make sure you are selecting the elements you think you are.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you have posted as far as I can see.  I would look elsewhere.  Start by validating your code and making sure you have fixed any syntax or structural errors.

Also, have you considered that there might be an element in front of the thing you are clicking?  For instance, an empty part of another element being overlaid.  Use a DOM inspector to check.

Comment: Tried this, elements get selected.

Answer (score 0):

In line 123 of ajax.js you replace the content:

`$('#container').html(json.content);`

The new elements have, of course, no handlers attached. You either have to bind the handler to the new elements or you bind it to an ancestor element in the first place.

Comment: As I said, on the first call there's no ajax call so handlers should be attached.

Comment: Yes, there is. For in the onload handler on line 93 in main.js you find this little statement: `firstVisit = false;`